# Month() function does not return the correct value

Tags: vba, excel

I want to determine the Month of my `startDate` but with the help of the VBA `month()` function I always get a full date (here: *07.01.1900*) returned. Any ideas how I can easily determine the `startMonth`? Thanks in advance for the help!

Here is my code:

```
Sub Calc()

Dim length As Long
Dim startDate As Date
Dim endDate As Date
Dim startMonth As Integer

startDate = Range("C2").Value      '22.07.2016
endDate = Range("P2").Value        '26.10.2016
length= endDate - startDate
startMonth = Month(startDate) 

Range("E5").Value = length        'returns 96
Range("E6").Value = startMonth    'returns 07.01.1900 instead of 7


End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like you just have the wrong cell format in E6 - format it to General instead of date.

Comment: what's in cell `U2` that you're getting start month from?

Comment: Why don't just use `month()` with your `startDate` variable instead of `U2` cell?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
With Range("E6")
    .Value = startMonth
    .NumberFormat = "#"
End With
```

or .NumberFormat = "0#" if you want to see the leading 0.

Answer (score 0):

The code you gave us doesn't seem to use the Month() function like you mentioned. Have you tried

```
startMonth = Month(Range("U2").Value)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I accidentally copied the wrong version. Now it contains the Month() function in startMonth= Month(startDate)

Answer (score 0):

Your cell `E6` is formatted as `Date`. Format it as a Standard cell and it will give you the expected result.

Having said this, there is a better way to get the difference of periods (months, or days or years) between two dates:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Debug.Print DateDiff("m", "22.07.2016", "26.10.2016") 'difference in months
    Debug.Print DateDiff("d", "22.07.2016", "26.10.2016") 'difference in days
    Debug.Print DateDiff("y", "22.07.2016", "26.10.2016") 'difference in years
End Sub
```

[DateDiff MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262712(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: @Rory - I think that the original code needs the difference in months of two dates.

Comment: On what basis? There's nothing that indicates that as far as I can see.

Comment: @Rory - the OP is using `length= endDate - startDate` - obviously he needs difference between the two periods. The `DateDiff` smooths this.

Comment: Yes but he's recording it in **days**, not months. I can't see any benefit to using `DateDiff` over `-` for that.

Comment: @Rory - in this specific case there is no benefit of `DateDiff` over `-`. However, in general, `DateDiff` is better because it checks the dates for being valid and a `-` will not do this. See that in the immediate window `Debug.Print "31.02.2016" - "26.10.2016"` returns a result.

Comment: Better is very subjective! I don't understand your last point, I'm afraid, as that just errors.

Comment: @Rory - write `Debug.Print "31.02.2016" - "26.10.2016"` in the immediate window.

Comment: I did - it returns a Type Mismatch error. It's not important anyway, since you've amended your answer. ;)

Comment: @Rory The distinction here is very important actually. The point @Vityata is trying to make is that, if the input is a value that doesn't match the expectation such as the string representation of a `Date`, and not a true `Date`. the `datediff()` function will implicitly force the conversion and prevent a run-time error. Additionally, the precision and readability of the `datediff()` function lends itself to cleaner code that is easier to debug. It also allows the user to easily change the calculation without adding anything fancy (if he wanted the difference in months, or years for example).

Comment: @BrandonBarney I'd nod to your last point about adaptability, though you are assuming the calculation would change. The other point I don't get - `DateDiff` returns the same type mismatch error if I pass it an invalid date string like "31/02/2016". TBH, I'd be worried if it didn't.

Comment: @Rory You're missing the `Implicit` conversion helping you out there. If the read was **always** from a cell, and **always** implicitly converted to a date, then there is a minute difference between the two. But what happens when the cell reads as a `String` but really it is the `String` representation of a `Date`? The `-` operator throws an error, the `datediff` first tries to do an `Implicit` conversion from `String` to `Date` before throwing an error.

Comment: Additionally, I would caution you from **ever** assuming your code won't change. I've made that mistake many times, and put string-literals, and hard-coded values all over the place. Guess what? I now have to fix all of those because requirements change. Its part of the job. We should always strive for adaptability, in our code, not rigidity.

Comment: @BrandonBarney That is all well and good, but you're actually completely ignoring the question at hand. There are two date variables so any conversion already happened. Do I agree that `DateDiff` is more flexible? Absolutely. Is it **better** for this question? Debatable. My initial point was rendered moot after this answer was changed, so I see no benefit to carrying this on.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a formatting issue.  Running:

```
Sub Calc()

    Dim length As Long
    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date
    Dim startMonth As Integer

    startDate = Range("C2").Value
    endDate = Range("P2").Value
    length = endDate - startDate
    startMonth = Month(startDate)

    Range("E5").Value = length
    Range("E6").Value = startMonth
End Sub
```

yields:

[image]